Integral of Bessel function involving complicated rational functions?
What will be the value of the $f(x,t)$ having
$$
\widetilde{f}(\text{x}, \xi)=\int_{0}^{\infty} r^{n/2}
\left(r^{2} + r^{2s}\right)^{-\xi}
\operatorname{J}_{n/2 - 1}\left(|x|r\right)
{\rm d}r\ ,
$$
where $\tilde{}$ denotes the Mellin transform, $\xi$ is the parameter w.r.t. Mellin transform, $s \in \left(0,1\right),\ b > 0,$ and $\operatorname{J}_{n}\left(z\right)$ is a Bessel Function of First Kind of order $n$ in variable $z$.

I can find the value of a similar kind of integral where $r^{2s} = a^{2}$ from the literature, but what will be the exact value of the integral given in the above form in my question?
What will be the value of the integral? And after evaluating this integral how can I take the inverse Mellin transform to get the value of function $f(x,t)$?

Can anyone help me to find the value of this integral?

Many integrals of Bessel functions can be found in the following book: https://docplayer.gr/154370-Tables-of-some-indefinite-integrals-of-bessel-functions.html

Using Mellin Transform for BesselJ function for $b$ parameter where $b=1$.Solving integral and at the and get Inverse Mellin Transform  for parameter q:
$$\widetilde{f}(\text{x}, \xi)=\int_0^{\infty } r^{n/2} \left(r^2+r^{2 s}\right)^{-\xi } J_{\frac{n}{2}-1}(b|x| r) \, dr=\\
\mathcal{M}_q^{-1}\left[\int_0^{\infty } r^{n/2} \left(r^2+r^{2 s}\right)^{-\xi } \mathcal{M}_b\left[J_{\frac{n}{2}-1}(b|x|
   r)\right](q) \, dr\right](1)=\\\mathcal{M}_q^{-1}\left[\int_0^{\infty } \frac{r^{n/2}
   \left(r^2+r^{2 s}\right)^{-\xi } \left(2^{-1+q} r^{-q}|x|^{-q} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-1+\frac{n}{2}\right)+\frac{q}{2}\right)\right)}{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{2} \left(-1+\frac{n}{2}\right)-\frac{q}{2}\right)}
   \, dr\right](1)=\\\mathcal{M}_q^{-1}\left[\frac{2^{-1+q}|x|^{-q} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4} (-2+n+2 q)\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{2+n-2 q-4 \xi }{4 (-1+s)}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{2+n-2 q-4 s \xi }{4-4 s}\right)}{(2-2 s) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4} (2+n-2
   q)\right) \Gamma (\xi )}\right](1) =\\\frac{1}{2 (2-2 s) \Gamma (\xi )}H^{2,1}_{1,3} \left[\frac{|x|}{2} \Bigg|
 \begin{matrix} 
 &\left\{-\frac{n}{4-4 s}+\frac{4 \xi  s}{4-4 s}-\frac{2}{4-4 s}+1,\frac{2}{4-4 s}\right\} \\
\left\{\frac{n}{4}-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right\},&\left\{\frac{n}{4 s-4}-\frac{4 \xi }{4 s-4}+\frac{2}{4 s-4},-\frac{2}{4 s-4}\right\}, & \left\{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right\}
\end{matrix}\right]$$
for: $n>0$
and using defintion of FoxH function we have (Mathematica code below):
 f[n_, x_, s_, \[Xi]_] := NIntegrate[
 r^(n/2)*(r^2 + r^(2*s))^-\[Xi]*BesselJ[n/2 - 1, Abs[x]*r], {r, 0,Infinity}];

 g[n_, x_, s_, \[Xi]_] := 1/(2 (2 - 2 s)  Gamma[\[Xi]])*
 FoxH[{{{1 - 2/(4 - 4 s) - n/(4 - 4 s) + (4 s \[Xi])/(4 - 4 s), 2/(
 4 - 4 s)}}, {}}, {{{-(1/2) + n/4, 1/
 2}, {2/(-4 + 4 s) + n/(-4 + 4 s) - (4 \[Xi])/(-4 + 4 s), -(
 2/(-4 + 4 s))}}, {{1/2 - n/4, 1/2}}}, 1/2 Abs[x]] // 
 FunctionExpand // N
 {f[4, 1/3, 2/3, 12/10], g[4, 1/3, 2/3, 12/10]}

 (*{1.17838, 1.17838}*)

and  take the inverse Mellin transform to get the value of function $f(x,t)$:
$$f(x,t)=\mathcal{M}_{\xi }^{-1}[\widetilde{f}(\text{x}, \xi)](t)=\\\mathcal{M}_{\xi }^{-1}[\frac{1}{2 (2-2 s) \Gamma (\xi )}H^{2,1}_{1,3} \left[\frac{|x|}{2} \Bigg|
 \begin{matrix} 
 &\left\{-\frac{n}{4-4 s}+\frac{4 \xi  s}{4-4 s}-\frac{2}{4-4 s}+1,\frac{2}{4-4 s}\right\} \\
\left\{\frac{n}{4}-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right\},&\left\{\frac{n}{4 s-4}-\frac{4 \xi }{4 s-4}+\frac{2}{4 s-4},-\frac{2}{4 s-4}\right\}, & \left\{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right\}
\end{matrix}\right]](t)$$
I doubt there's a closed form for Inverse Mellin transform for general parameters.
For simple case ,let: $n=2$ and $s=0$ we have:
$$f(x,t)=\mathcal{M}_{\xi }^{-1}[\widetilde{f}(\text{x}, \xi)](t)=\\\mathcal{M}_{\xi }^{-1}\left[\frac{2^{1-\xi } | x| ^{-1+\xi } K_{-1+\xi }(| x| )}{\Gamma (\xi )}\right](t)=\\ \frac{J_0\left(\sqrt{-1+\frac{1}{t}} | x| \right) \left(1-\theta (-1+t)+\theta (1-t) \theta (-1+t)^2\right)}{2 t}$$
For simple case ,let only: $s=0$ we have:
$$f(x,t)=\mathcal{M}_{\xi }^{-1}[\widetilde{f}(\text{x}, \xi)](t)=\\\mathcal{M}_{\xi }^{-1}\left[\frac{2^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2-n}{4}+\frac{n}{4}-\xi } | x| ^{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} (-2+n)-\frac{n}{4}+\xi } K_{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2-n}{4}-\frac{n}{4}+\xi }(| x| )}{\Gamma (\xi
   )}\right](t)=\\-\frac{\left(-1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^{\frac{2+n}{4}} J_{\frac{1}{2} (-2+n)}\left(\sqrt{-1+\frac{1}{t}} | x| \right) \left(1-\theta (-1+t)+\theta (1-t) \theta (-1+t)^2\right)}{2 (-1+t)}+\sum _{m=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{2^{-\frac{n}{2}} \left(-1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^{n/2} | x| ^{-1+\frac{n}{2}} \left(-\frac{1}{4} \left(-1+\frac{1}{t}\right) | x| ^2\right)^m \theta \left(1-m-\frac{n}{2}\right) \theta (1-t) \theta (-1+t)^2}{(-1+t) m! \Gamma
   \left(m+\frac{n}{2}\right)}$$
where: $K$ is modified Bessel function of the second kind.
$J_0$ is the Bessel function of the first kind.
$\theta$ is HeavisideTheta function.

Thank you so much sir for your reply. Could you help me out with my modified problem? I will be highly thankful for this help.

@user1448137 .I update the answer.

I have two doubts:

In my problem the integral is equal to the Mellin transform of f(x, t) i.e. $\widetilde{f}(\text{x}, \xi)$, and I want to evaluate the value of f(x,t). For this, I have to take the inverse of the Mellin transform on both sides but before evaluating the value of integrals I am unable to take the inverse of the Mellin transform.
In the current reply, how you have written the first line? That is, how we can write the value of the given integral in terms of the inverse of the Mellin transform and Mellin transform as mentioned above in the first line?


Kernel of the Mellin transform is different as:
$$ \widetilde{f}(\xi)=\mathcal{M} [f(t), \xi]=\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\xi-1} f(t)dt,$$
and
$$f(t)=\mathcal{M}^{-1}[\widetilde{f}(\xi), t]:=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+\infty} t^{-\xi} \widetilde{f}(\xi) d\xi.$$
But in my problem, the kernel is not $t^{\xi-1}$ as mentioned in Mellin Transform. In my problem the weight is $r^{\frac{n}{2}} \left( r^2 + r^{2s} \right)^{-\xi}$.
So I am unable to understand, how one can write the first line given as in your solution.
Kindly clarify my doubts.

@user1448137 This will clear everything up:$$J_{\frac{n}{2}-1}(| x|  r)=\\mathcal{M}_q^{-1}\left[\mathcal{M}_b\leftJ_{\frac{n}{2}-1}(b | x|  r)\right\right](b)=\\mathcal{M}q^{-1}\left\frac{2^{-1+q} r^{-q} | x| ^{-q} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}
\left(-1+\frac{n}{2}\right)+\frac{q}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{2} \left(-1+\frac{n}{2}\right)-\frac{q}{2}\right)}\right=\J{\frac{n}{2}-1}(| x|  r)$$

Can we take $\mathcal{M}{q}^{-1}$ outside the integration? Because this inverse is associated with only the Bessel function $J{\frac{n}{2}-1} (|x|r)$, so how we can take inverse outside to the whole integration part?

@user1448137I wrote it: "Using Mellin Transform for BesselJ function for b
parameter where b=1
.Solving integral and at the and get Inverse Mellin Transform for parameter q:" It can't be explained any better.
